Won't get nested Sanity array/references to work
I want to build a array that takes my other schema-components so that the user can choose which element they want to have. I then built a textBlock object to have in my other components that I referenced in my main document. Everything works as I want in Sanity Studio but I can't figure out why it dosen't work on the page - it says that it can't read {block.offerContent.content}.
I'm appreciative of all given help!!
Products page (main document)
import { defineArrayMember, defineField, defineType } from "sanity";

const products = defineType({
  name: "products",
  title: "Products",
  type: "document",
  fields: [
    defineField({
      name: "title",
      title: "Title",
      type: "string",
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "slug",
      title: "Slug",
      type: "slug",
      options: {source: 'title'}
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "headerText",
      title: "Header text",
      type: "text",
    }),
    defineField({
      name: "headerImage",
      title: "Header bild",
      type: "image",
      options: { hotspot: true },
      fields: [
        {
          name: "alt",
          title: "Alt",
          type: "string",
        },
      ],
    }),
    defineField({
      name: 'content',
      type: 'array',
      title: 'Innehåll',
      of: [
        defineArrayMember({
          type: 'advantages',
        }),
        defineArrayMember({
          type: 'offer',
        }),
        defineArrayMember({
          type: 'faq',
        }),
      ]
    }),
  ],
});

export default products;

Offer component
import { defineField, defineType } from "sanity";

const offer = defineType({
  name: "offer",
  title: "Hur vi kan hjälpa till",
  type: "object",
  fields: [
    defineField({
        title: 'Titel',
        name: 'title',
        type: 'string',
    }),
    defineField({
        title: 'Inledande text',
        name: 'text',
        type: 'text',
    }),
    defineField({
        title: 'Innehåll',
        name: 'offerContent',
        type: 'textBlock',
    }),
    ],
});

export default offer;

TextBlock component
import { defineField, defineType } from "sanity";

const textBlock = defineType({
  name: "textBlock",
  title: "Text block",
  type: "object",
  fields: [
    defineField({ 
      title: 'Text',
      name: 'content',
      type:'array',
      of: [{type: "block"}],   
    }),
    ],
});

export default textBlock;

My groq query
export async function getProduct(slug: string){
    return createClient(clientConfig).fetch(
        groq`*[_type == "products" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
        _id,
        _createdAt,
        title,
        "slug": slug.current,
        headerText,
        headerImage{
            asset->{
              _id,
              url
            }
          },
        content[]{
        _type == "offer" => {
        _type,
        title,
        text,
        offerContent{content},
        }
        }
        }`,
        {slug}
    )
}

Page where I want to display it:
import { getProduct } from "@/sanity/sanity-utils";
import { PortableText } from "@portabletext/react";
import Image from "next/image";

type Props = {
  params: { product: string };
};

export default async function Product({ params }: Props) {
  const slug = params.product;
  const product = await getProduct(slug);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{product.title}</h1>

      <PortableText value={product.headerText} />
      {product.image ? (
        <Image
          src={product.headerImage}
          alt={product.alt}
          width={1000}
          height={1000}
        />
      ) : null}

      <div>
        {product.content.map((block: any, index: any) => {
          switch (block._type) {
            case "offer":
              return (
                <div key={index}>
                  <p>{block.title}</p>
                  <p>{block.text}</p>
                  <h2>{block.offerContent.content}</h2>
                </div>
              );

            default:
              return null;
          }
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


{block.offerContent.title} Shouldn't this be {block.offerContent.content} ? since your Text block object doesn't have a title field, also why would anyone use PortableText for a title, so i'm thinking you want to say {block.offerContent.content}

You're right. I saw that when i published but when I change to content it doesn't word either...Did you see anything more that could of caused the problem?

I'm not familiar with GROQ, try to log the offerContent object and see what it returns, if other  block fields are working properly, then the problem should be narrowed to offerContent alone
